# Passing @Url.Content as parameter in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I am building a custom control in ASP MVC using razor generator. It will take an image as parameter. I want to be able to make the method call in my view like this

```
 @Html.MyMethod(@Url.Content("~/Content/images/photo1.jpg"))
```

I want to know what is the type of the @Url.Content so that I can declare it in the definition of MyMethod.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a second `@` here. Return type of `Url.Content` is `System.String`.

Answer (score 2):

`MyMethod` can take a string as `Content` returns a string:

```
public static IHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper helper, string url)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString("<img src=\"" + url + "\" />");
}
```

Also, you won't need the `@` operator:

```
@Html.MyMethod(Url.Content("~/Content/images/photo1.jpg"))
```